# TileMap with swing (Java)

Tags: java, swing, frameworks

i'm looking for [this](http://www.interactivepulp.com/pulpcore/tilemap/) effect, but PulpCore doen't works with swing. Do you know what library use, or how to make a TileMap? Also, I'd like to move forever in it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you don't want to use an actual world-map implementation like [JXMapViewer](http://www.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/10/30/building-maps-into-swing-app-with-jxmapviewer.html)...

The basic functionality appears to be: click on some coordinates, and that point becomes centered in the viewport. One fairly simple way to do this is to have the component(s) that you want to view all contained within a `JPanel` and have that panel inside a `JScrollPane` with its scrollbars turned off (`setHorizontalScrollbarPolicy(HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER)` and so on).  Then, set up a click or action listener for your elements that calculates the new center point, what the new viewport rectangle coordinates will be, and use `scrollRectToVisible` on the panel to shift the view.  For animation, you can use a Swing `Timer` to set up a series of incremental scrolls in the required direction until you reach the target.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I found [this](http://java-swing-tips.blogspot.com/2008/06/mouse-drag-auto-scrolling.html) example, it works just the way you recomended me.